# Как сделать перенаправление через .htaccess по расширениям?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Как сделать перенаправление через .htaccess по расширениям? Например, расширение `.inc` направляется на `404.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретный пример направления:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.inc$ 404.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте про директиву [RedirectMatch](http://weblomaster.ru/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-apache-redirect-redirectmatch-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8/) - редирект с использованием регулярных выражений.